# Dystopia where you're watched but NOT 1984

Tags: story-identification, tv

I watched this on British tv in the late 1960s/early 1970s - no later than 72..I remember it was black and white but my parents never got a colour TV until 1976!

It was a B movie or a TV movie set in a society similar to 1984 and Big Brother, you were watched for signs of dissent against the government - however this society had a fully fledged rebel organisation with secret codes and hideouts.

One scene a couple of rebels were watching rebel captives being taken to execution, they were mouthing hatred along with the other onlookers while simultaneously passing whispered instructions to one another.
I **think** an armed uprising was being planned.

I think the accents were a weird sort of mid Atlantic so probably it was intended for both the US and the UK

Unfortunately my mother decided she wanted to watch some old romantic drama so I never saw what happened

Comment: I did a quick scan through TVTropes's [Big Brother is Watching](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BigBrotherIsWatching) page, but nothing popped out. So the chief distinguishing factor is this secret society with coded phrases?

Comment: Yeah, the secret society...so like BB but a whole mob of rebels, not just a loving couple. I remember thinking at the time (we'd just been reading it at school) "Hey, this is a bit like that story"

Comment: The first thing I thought of was Yevgeny Zamyatin's _[We](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_(novel))_ but there weren't any adaptations in the late 60's / early 70's. Another possibility is _[Logan's Run](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logan%27s_Run_(film))_.

Comment: No not Logan's Run, I remember going to watch that in the cinema with my mates as a teenager

Comment: Could it have been [Fahrenheit 451](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060390/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_3). It's a colour movie, but you say you didn't get a colour TV until 1976. It's based on a book by Ray Bradbury. The movie is kind of B, and the 2018 remake is even worse.

Comment: For what it's worth, my parents only got a color TV in the mid to late 90's. 1976 is peanuts! :P

Comment: I was thinking of Terry Gilliam's movie [*Brazil*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088846/), but that was in 1985 so a bit too late.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A possibility is *[Home Sweet Honeycomb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063078/?ref_=kw_li_tt)*, an episode in the anthology series Theatre 625, and broadcast May 13 1968. Screen adaptation of a play.

> Fantasy about a world where anyone who does not conform to bourgeois norms is ritually executed.

Some information about the play [here](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Anger_and_After_Routledge_Revivals/ifFkAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Home%20Sweet%20Honeycomb%22%20bernard%20kops&pg=PA179&printsec=frontcover) and [here](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Beyond_Marginality/L5sbPgQ86CIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Home%20Sweet%20Honeycomb%22%20bernard%20kops&pg=PA53&printsec=frontcover).

About the right date, the right country, and fits the general sort of theme.

Sadly, the episode [no longer exists.](https://www.tvbrain.info/tv-archive?showname=theatre%20625&type=lostshow)

Comment: I think that's probably it, well done and thanks

Answer (score 1):

Mayhaps, [The Prisoner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prisoner) (1967 UK)

> I am not a number; I AM A FREE MAN!

I haven't actually watched it but I do remember the commercials for it - very dark and dystopian with some strange white balloon that monitors everyone in the town. The theme and the year fit.

> Although internal physical movement of residents around the Village is unconstrained, the premises are secured by numerous high-tech monitoring systems and security forces, including a balloon-like automaton called Rover, that recaptures or kills those who attempt escape. The man encounters the Village's population, hundreds of people from all walks of life and cultures, all seeming to be peacefully and mostly enjoyably living out their lives. They do not use names, but have been assigned numbers which, aside from designations such as Two, Three, and Six, give no clue as to any person's status within the Village, whether as prisoners or guards. Potential escapees, therefore, have no idea whom they can and cannot trust.

It had a somewhat distinctive look - the main guy seemed to wear these suits with the outlined lapels.

[image: Man wearing a black suit with white stripes on the lapels]

[IMDB - The Prisoner](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061287/?ref_=ttmi_tt)

Comment: Hmmmm... Active on SF&F, but has never watched The Prisoner. I can only conclude that you are a spy in the vanguard of an alien invasion of the Earth...

Comment: That's mostly just about 1 guy in 1 small town though.  Not an entire society.  (There are other people apparently also being watched, but if they're not just background extras, they pretty much always turn out to be watchers themselves, or they're killed off in the same episode in which they're introduced - sometimes both.)

Comment: An incredible series, but doesn't really match the OP's description.

Comment: Never watched this, but it clearly inspired a kickass Maiden song: https://youtu.be/a7LH__BPqSY